# Are Extraordinary Ministers of the Eucharistic allowed to break the host?

Tags: catholicism, communion, sacraments, ministry, extraordinary-ministers

I'd like to know if Eucharistic Ministers are allowed to break a consecrated host?

I witnessed this happening and I didn't think they had the right to do it.

I was searching for the answer but some say yes and another no. Is there any official teaching or how do I find out if it's ok in my parish or diocese?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The official website of the Vatican seems to be silent on this issue. Nevertheless it may be up to the local ordinary to make special norms for the diocese in question!

The following is taken from [Redemptionis Sacramentum](http://www.vatican.va//roman_curia/congregations/ccdds/documents/rc_con_ccdds_doc_20040423_redemptionis-sacramentum_en.html) of the Vatican:

> [160.] Let the diocesan Bishop give renewed consideration to the practice in recent years regarding this matter, and if circumstances call for it, let him correct it or define it more precisely. Where such extraordinary ministers are appointed in a widespread manner out of true necessity, the diocesan Bishop should issue special norms by which he determines the manner in which this function is to be carried out in accordance with the law, bearing in mind the tradition of the Church.

Answer (score 0):

Lay "Eucharistic Ministers" are a post-Vatican II novelty, as is Communion in the hand. The actual norms only permit them in cases of grave necessity (e.g., in regions where there is no priest). See, e.g., *[The Eucharistic Storms: Communion in the hand and marginalizing the Real Presence](https://isidore.co/calibre/browse/book/5073)* by Barry Forbes.

Comment: This doesn't seem to answer the question, which was, "are they allowed to break the host?"

Comment: @Ward I think Geremia's point is that, if one asks about the *official rules* of the post-Vatican II religion, then lay Eucharistic ministers are, in the absence of grave necessity, not even permitted to handle the consecrated hosts. A fortiori, they would not be permitted to break consecrated hosts.

Comment: @AndreasBlass Not quite.  It does not require grave necessity for a  lay Eucharistic minister to handle the host (it's done as a routine each mass in the post vatican II world that some people keep rejecting) but to break it in lieu of the clergy so doing.

Comment: @Ward If they're not allowed to touch the Host, why should they be allowed to break It?

Comment: @Geremia, let's say you're right. Am I committing a sacrilege if I receive the Eucharist from a Eucharistic minister?

Answer (score -3):

A eucharistic minister is only a person. An ordained Catholic priest is the only person allowed to touch the consecrated host .o Only a concecrated priest is allowed to touch it. Lay people are commitimg sacriledge.

Comment: Eucharistic ministers are lay people, but first, the word eucharistic ministers is not even a valid terminology of the Catholic faith. It does not exist. It never hasvexisted in the Catholi c Church. It is made up by anti God people. Only a validly ordained Catholic priest, excluding the new mass priests, Whose hands are consecrated are allowed to touch a valid Catholic host. His hands are consecrated for the jib. Only consecrated items are allowed to touch consecrated things. Look up on the internet Fr. Grunner on eucharistic ministers. He knows of many interesting Catholic laws.

Comment: On what basis can you support this answer?  You  may or may not be right, but none of us can tell based on the sparse text,  unsupported, that you provide.  Please review [how to answer](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer) and revise you answer to include support for your statements.

Comment: Please see [what makes a good supported answer](https://christianity.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/692/what-makes-a-good-supported-answer?r=SearchResults&s=1|77.5078).

Comment: [Fr. Nicholaus Gruner](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/50105/are-extraordinary-ministers-of-the-eucharistic-allowed-to-break-the-host/68709#68709) is a suspended priest.